# iPhone 3GS - is it still possible to restore to latest supported iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, jailbreak, restore

I have an iPhone 3GS that I want to restore to latest supported iOS (currently it's jailbroken on some version of iOS 4.0.1).

How would I go about it, without loosing all data? Can I run a restore from iTunes? Latest version of iTunes (12.2.1) doesn't even recognize that I have a device plugged in.

Edit:
I don't want to restore another jailbreak version. I want to restore a "proper" iOS

Comment: If anyone has a discussion on voting - please take it to [meta] and avoid disparaging words.

Comment: The obvious answer would be to back up the device data, erase and upgrade and then restore the backup. Is there a reason why this wouldn't work? The question seems to allude to hardware issues - but perhaps iTunes doesn't recognize jailbroken devices - I'm not sure if that's a known side effect. In the mean time - please update the post with details. What version of iTunes? What version of iOS is running and have you selected to upgrade to. "Latest" is a bad term since a) posts age b) different people have access to different "latest" builds.

Comment: "The obvious answer" is not obvious, else it wouldn't be a question (don't know where I ever alluded to hardware at all...). @AntonTodorov was #SOreadytohelp, unlike others. To avoid cluttering the question with multiple issues (which could never receive a proper accepted answer), I separated the theoretical "know-how" question (this one), from the "doesn't-work-for-me" question (here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199112/iphone-3gs-jailbreak-not-recognized-in-itunes). In there, I detail all versions and steps I tried.

Comment: Well done - more questions that are narrow is the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest you to check and find a version of iTunes that supports your iPhone 3GS.

Secondly, you could backup your iPhone, but be aware that a backup could bring the issue back after the phone is freshly restored.

Next, I can suggest to check and find a pre-activation method(as far as I remember RedSn0w was able to do that) and create a pre-activated IPSW file for yourself.

Also have on mind the specificity of the Firmware's BaseBand version of the iPhone, of you will need to unlock (after jailbreak) your phone.

Comment: I want to restore/upgrade to proper iOS, not another jailbreak. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: The answer above still applies.

Comment: I still cannot get my phone recognized by iTunes (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199112/iphone-3gs-jailbreak-not-recognized-in-itunes), but I guess this would be the correct answer if that would have worked